# Safety of a Galaxy Note 7 with a non-factory battery

Tags: battery, hardware, samsung-galaxy-note-7

**Backstory** The now-infamous Galaxy Note7 was recalled by Samsung twice (and finally completely canceled) for its exploding batteries. After Samsung's long investigation into the cause of the explosions, they determined that the only issue both the original and post-recall models of the Note7 were manufacturing issues with the batteries themselves, as [reported by The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2017/1/22/14353686/samsung-galaxy-note-7-recall-reason-report).

**Question** Given that the only things making the Note7s explosive is their batteries, is it reasonably safe to pick up an explosive Note7 and immediately replace its battery with one not made by Samsung? And is there a Note7 replacement battery available that's not one of the Samsung originals that will explode? If this is possible, it might be possible to get an amazing (and safe) phone quite cheaply.

---

Note: I have no plans to do any such thing even if it is technically safe and I highly discourage others from trying to buy/use a Note 7.

Comment: Given that the reason of battery failure is the incompatibility between the over-capacity battery and phone's battery containment space... will any manufacturers produce batteries that are *smaller* in capacity than the original? My bet is not.

Comment: What is the guarantee that non OEM battery won't explode? Like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/172680/danger-why-you-shouldnt-buy-cheap-third-party-batteries-for-laptops-or-smartphones/)

Comment: @AndyYan Smart. Especially given that there are no replacement batteries for it so far as I can tell. Can you consider posting that as an answer?

Comment: @beeshyams No guarantee. But in theory, if the non-OEM battery was a high-quality one rather than a cheap counterfeit?

Comment: That's a contradiction. Non OEM batteries are cheaper , since 1. Their quality and performance is not subject to same quality checks as OEM (though that's failed with Note 7) 2. While batteries are usually not covereded under warranty, if they underperform, you can still raise a stink and the company wouldn't like it - with non OEM, it's take it or leave it. But if you are sure that it is high quality and the battery chip does all that original battery does, then it's fine IMO

Comment: @beeshyams So basically, you're saying there was/will just never be a safe battery made for the Note7? Makes sense, especially given that iFixit only makes replacements for iPhones (there's could be safe maybe?).

Comment: No. But unlikely that non OEM would produce batteries, when of high quality given that the device is recalled and when it can't be guaranteed

Comment: So just imagine this scenario:  Your self-modified phone suffers a malfunction and burns someone or worse.  Investigation reveals it is not the same as the manufacturer built.  Who do you think would be on the hook with the insurance company for reimbursement for damages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the reason of battery failure is the incompatibility between the *over-capacity* battery and phone's battery containment space, manufacturers are unlikely going to produce batteries that are *smaller* in capacity than the original, considering they usually make *bigger* ones for profit and marketing purposes. They also manufacture them in generally worse materials and quality control in order to control costs. This renders those 3rd-party batteries (if any exists) as dangerous, if not more dangerous as the original one.

Also, since Note 7 has been recalled for quite some time, manufacturers have (nearly) ceased production of any sort of accessories for it - nobody's buying them anyway. Here's what I dug up from my local shopping site TaoBao (Chinese equivalent of eBay) - if you can't read Chinese, the page shows that only "original" batteries are available, and even those are available in very small quantities (few resellers list them).

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detailed answer :). I'll definitely be sticking to my Nexus for a while longer.